# Cucumber-reports defining an environment variable

Tags: java, cucumber, report, cucumber-java

I would like to send my cucumber reports to [cucumber-reports cloud(?)](https://reports.cucumber.io/) but the page requires to set up some environment variables like you see on the picture. But I am not sure what it exactly mean and how to do it. I would like to to do it in Java code which will load this value from config file. But really don't know what they mean.

[image]

Can somebody tell me how to do it right? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to set environment variables depends on your operating system.

Try this: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html

Comment: Is it possible to do it in the Java code? This does not sound much portable.